# D3 SVG from an external js file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How do I have D3 related commands in an external js file.

When I put these commands in  tag inside  tag of index.html, it works.  However when I move these cmds into an external js file, it doesn't work.  Did I miss something or it's not possible to call D3 from another js file.

```
//this works
<body>
        <script>
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

            svg.attr("width", 250);
            svg.attr("height", 250);

            var rect = svg.append("rect");

            rect.attr("x", 50);
            rect.attr("y", 50);
            rect.append("style", "fill:blue");
            rect.attr("width", 80);
            rect.attr("height", 80);
        </script>
</body>
//this doesn't work
//inside bhha.js. 
//bhha.js is called from <script> tag in the main html
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

svg.attr("width", 250);
svg.attr("height", 250);

var rect = svg.append("rect");

rect.attr("x", 150);
rect.attr("y", 150);
rect.attr("width", 20);
rect.attr("height", 20);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you added your external JS file in `<head>` it might not work. If you put your external JS script in `<body>`, it would work. Try below, it worked for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.2/d3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="bhha.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```